# how to save data through javascript in select list in crm

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I am adding a selectlist in my web resource and then saving the data through JavaScript like this

```
entity.attributes['new_category'] = categoryValue;
```

where

```
categoryValue = $("#category option:selected")[0].innerHTML
```

But when i am creating the entity like

```
XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.Create(entity)
```

[it is throwing me and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pe9ig.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to assign option set values using `XrmServiceToolkit`, which `new_category` does look like it is, you need to assign the value like so:

```
entity.attributes["new_category"] = { value: categoryValue, type: "OptionSetValue" };
```